# Nested append to an Array in Julia

Tags: julia

In python this would be something like:

```
Z = []
z = 1
Z.append([z])
```

which would create `Z= [[1]]` for example. But in Julia, I cannot seem to re-create the same structure. I can append, but don't know how to nest. Here is what I am doing in summary:

```
Z = []
# loop
z = dotProduct(X, yArray) # single digit
append!(Z, z)
```

which then generates the following

```
0Any[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

where as I would like:

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

What is the best way to do this in Julia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to make this work was the following:

```
Z = Array{Int64,1}[]
push!(Z, [1])
push!(Z, [2])
print(Z)
```

giving

```
Array{Int64,1}[[1], [2]]
```

Not very elegant, but I cannot seem to get this working without the Array keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps?

```
julia> Z = Array{Array{Int64,1},1}[]
0-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}

julia> push!(Z, [[1]])
1-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}:
[[1]]

julia> push!(Z, [[2]])
2-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}:
[[1]]
[[2]]

julia> push!(Z[1], [3])
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
[1]
[3]

julia> Z
2-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}:
[[1], [3]]
[[2]]
```