# Pushing arrays of one variable in one array

Tags: julia

I have this piece of code:

```
for i=1:10
    v=[2i,i]
    @show v
    end
```

and I get this result:

```
v = [2, 1]
v = [4, 2]
v = [6, 3]
v = [8, 4]
v = [10, 5]
v = [12, 6]
v = [14, 7]
v = [16, 8]
v = [18, 9]
v = [20, 10]
```

Now what I want to do is to collect all these outputs of into one array of arrays, something like:
`[[2,1],[4,2],[6,3]]`

and I don't really know how to do it, I've tried several solutions that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested append to an Array in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741949/nested-append-to-an-array-in-julia)

Comment: Maybe I've answered to soon: in your example [9,3] doesn't show up in your loop?

Comment: @laborg i just wanted to write `[6,3]` it was just a mistake, anyway i guess the kind of output that i'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array comprehensions for this:

```
julia> x = [[2i,i] for i in 1:10]
10-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [2, 1]  
 [4, 2]  
 [6, 3]  
 [8, 4]  
 [10, 5] 
 [12, 6] 
 [14, 7] 
 [16, 8] 
 [18, 9] 
 [20, 10]
```

or go with the manual route of constructing an empty initial array, and pushing the inner arrays into it one-by-one:

```
julia> y = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> for i in 1:10
           push!(y,[2i,i])
       end

julia> y
10-element Array{Any,1}:
 [2, 1]  
 [4, 2]  
 [6, 3]  
 [8, 4]  
 [10, 5] 
 [12, 6] 
 [14, 7] 
 [16, 8] 
 [18, 9] 
 [20, 10]
```